# Replace values in one column with values from another column omitting nans python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a df like this

```
     Estado         Estado_OMM
     SUSPENDIDA     CLAUSURADA
     SUSPENDIDA     CLAUSURADA
     OPERATIVA      nan 
     PARCIALMENTE   nan
     OPERATIVA      nan
     OPERATIVA      OPERATIVA
```

I want to replace (only the values that are not nan) df['Estado'] to df['Estado_OMM'] (same row).

I tried this

```
for i in df['Estado_OMM']!=np.nan:
   df['Estado']=df['Estado_OMM']
```

Also i tried this

```
if df['Estado_OMM']!=np.nan:
   df['Estado']=df['Estado_OMM']
```

Noone works. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)**:

```
df['replaced_Estado'] = np.where(df['Estado_OMM'].notna(), df['Estado_OMM'], df['Estado'])
```

Output:

```
         Estado  Estado_OMM
0    CLAUSURADA  CLAUSURADA
1    CLAUSURADA  CLAUSURADA
2     OPERATIVA         NaN
3  PARCIALMENTE         NaN
4     OPERATIVA         NaN
5     OPERATIVA   OPERATIVA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mask = df['Estado_OMM'].notna()
>>> df.loc[mask, 'Estado'] = df.loc[mask, 'Estado_OMM']
>>> df

         Estado  Estado_OMM
0    CLAUSURADA  CLAUSURADA
1    CLAUSURADA  CLAUSURADA
2     OPERATIVA         NaN
3  PARCIALMENTE         NaN
4     OPERATIVA         NaN
5     OPERATIVA   OPERATIVA
```

Alternatively you could do it the other way around:

```
>>> df['Estado'] = df['Estado_OMM'].fillna(df['Estado'])
>>> df
         Estado  Estado_OMM
0    CLAUSURADA  CLAUSURADA
1    CLAUSURADA  CLAUSURADA
2     OPERATIVA         NaN
3  PARCIALMENTE         NaN
4     OPERATIVA         NaN
5     OPERATIVA   OPERATIVA
```